Load Runner - Correlate dynamic value
Below is the sample Body part from the request
Body=7|2|20|https://abc-def.ghi.abcdefgh.com/ui/uis/|cl.imp.search.comands.Command/123456|{c_DynVal}*|0-jhterv0|java.util.HashMap/
here {c_DynVal}= dynamic value which I am already corelating, but now "0-jhterv0" value is also dynamic.
I have tried below method:
    "ParamName=c_SearchNode",
    "LB=*|",
    "RB=|",
    SEARCH_FILTERS,
    "Scope=Body",
    LAST);    

But I am getting error:
Action.c(437): Error -26377: No match found for the requested parameter "c_SearchNode". Either the specified boundaries were not found in the response or the matched text is longer than current max html parameter size of 9999999 bytes. The total length of the response is 226 bytes. You can use "web_set_max_html_param_len" to increase the max parameter size.   [MsgId: MERR-26377]
since, I am new to Load Runner PT, please guide me on the same.

a). Have you had product training?
b). Do you have an assigned mentor as you are new to LoadRunner?
